# I am creating a hierarchy RBAC, should you use _grantRole or _setRoleAdmin first?

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, foundry

Was wondering if you should _grantRole first or _setRoleAdmin first based on OZ AccessControl

```
        _grantRole(CoreRoles.GOVERNOR, msg.sender);

        // Initial roles setup: direct hierarchy, everything under governor
        _setRoleAdmin(CoreRoles.GOVERNOR, CoreRoles.GOVERNOR);
```